# How to add information on different layers of OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

How can I add different layers on a map where each layer has some information?

So, when I enable all the layers, all the information is displayed and when I enable others only the information of those layers are displayed.

I need to know how to associate data with one layer. I can insert `map.overlayer(...)` but that is always visible.

Comment: Here you can find all your answers - https://openlayers.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved

You need to put an array of layers when creating your map

```
new OpenLayers.Map({
div: "map",
allOverlays: true,
layers: [layer1, layer2]}
```

and then customize any layer